# Database schema migration strategy for drupal 7

Tags: php, drupal-7

I am new to this topic and I don't know how Drupal 7 works on these directions.

Questions:

1. Are there any strategies to run database schema migrations like
   Symfony have Doctrine Migration Bundle?
2. How to safely update your database schema both locally and on
   production in drupal 7?
3. Since this is going to be like multi-branching strategies, how to
   keep everything updated?
4. How about multi-siting?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Answers on questions:

1. Drupal has migration modules. Will you migrate to Drupal 8(No answer need)?
2. No safety update for database(More bellow);
3. You will start new project with Drupal 8 version than you could apply this strategy as usual;
4. If you mean sub domains migration modules provide migration for that database what you indicate. You can make it for all your multi-site databases one by one.

### How migration from Drupal 7 to Drupal 8 goes.

1. Start new project on Drupal 8 core(on new server).
2. Find all contrib Drupal 7 modules, libs and themes versions on Drupal 8.
3. Transfer your data by migration module (migration,migration plus and more others). This is the main part of migration.
   Make custom modules with custom source plugins and YUML files for it.
4. Refactor your custom modules and themes, than use them at your new Drupal 8 site.

Comment: this would be the proper way to do it, but considering the current situation, the best solution that i found till now is (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1497346/drupal-database-deployment-strategies). A custom script(you can do it with drush to create command that gets the latest version on a migration file). You can save migration file name in a table with timestamp.

Comment: This module can be helpful too: Features or https://www.drupal.org/project/configuration

Comment: You can also use this https://www.drupal.org/project/drupalmoduleupgrader module to for up gradation of module from d7 to d8.