# Multiple environment (Development, Staging, Live) in Drupal

Tags: php, drupal, live, staging

I am sure the title is pretty much the question but I would like to explain a bit more...

Drupal is great CMS but it lacks of process to achieve multiple environment (Development -> Staging -> Live)

Why I need multiple environment?
For example, the site live and you want to add functionality or amend something, of course u do not want to directly go live so what you will do is actually go development first then if u have client then u go to staging then at last go to live...

So is there any way to achieve this?
Of course the option to overwrite the database completely is not an answer that I look for... Since the live has user-data in the database...

Thanks

Comment: Good question but this is a duplicate of this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1535580/how-are-people-handling-content-management-system-production-staging/1537017

Comment: Hi Jeremy, I am interested only in database... I saw a lot of comments to use the update script... but it just lot of hassle to do.. And it is huge possibility to make mistake as well... Is there any way to do database synch using tools to compare one by one that is tailored specific to drupal?

Comment: I don't believe so. And the difficulty of comparing databases is much more difficult than using an update script. The low tech alternative is to write down the changes you make to config and repeat the steps on each environment.

Answer (score 1):

You could take a look at [Capistrano](http://www.capify.org/) for deploying your app in multiple environments, automated of course.

Comment: Yep... that is must for the code deployment... how about the database?

Comment: I think Capistrano can do that as well with proper defined DDL's. But I haven't tried that yet.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Features module for this.

Comment: Yep, definitely features is promising module... but yet... it is quite complicated to use... I want something like easy but yet powerful...